How to create custom Google Maps marker icon in compose
How can I create a custom marker icon with custom text like this in compose?
Currently, I am creating this icon using pin config in advanced marker, but it causes lag, using pin config in advanced marker is not as smooth as normal marker.
Note: Bus Icon is built in map

Red Marker with 22222 text is created using
AdvancedMarker(
    state = markerState,
    pinConfig = marker.pinConfig,
    title = "hello",
    snippet = "World",
    alpha = alpha,
   
)

I want to use this marker where I can provide the above icon to this marker function
Marker(
    state = markerState,
    icon = 
)

I can not use the pin config in Marker(). it requires BitmapDescriptor

Are you using it on a map? what does normal marker mean, the bus symbol is a normal marker?

Yes, I am using it on the map. I have modified the question. I want to create a custom icon like a red icon with text 22222.

To create a marker as you have shown in the image you need to follow these steps.
Step 1. Create a Custom Marker Composable
@Composable
fun CustomMarkerView(text: String) {
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp)
            .background(Color.Red, shape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp))
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black, shape = RoundedCornerShape(50.dp))
    ) {
        Text(text, color = Color.White, fontSize = 16.sp)
    }
}

Step 2. Convert Composable to Bitmap
fun createMarkerBitmap(context: Context, text: String): Bitmap {
    // Create an empty Bitmap with a specific width, height, and config
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)  // Initialize a Canvas to draw on the bitmap

    // Get the device screen density (to scale things correctly)
    val density = context.resources.displayMetrics.density

    // Create a ComposeView that will render the composable into a view
    val composeView = ComposeView(context).apply {
        setContent {
            // Render the custom marker composable inside this ComposeView
            CustomMarkerView(text = text)
        }
    }

    // Measure and layout the ComposeView to be rendered correctly
    composeView.measure(
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((100 * density).toInt(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((100 * density).toInt(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
    )
    composeView.layout(0, 0, composeView.measuredWidth, composeView.measuredHeight)

    // Finally, draw the ComposeView on the Canvas (which is linked to the Bitmap)
    composeView.draw(canvas)

    return bitmap  // Return the resulting Bitmap with the custom composable drawn
}


Step 3. Use BitmapDescriptor in Google Maps Marker

val customMarkerBitmap = createMarkerBitmap(context, "22222")  // Create the bitmap with the desired text
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
    .position(LatLng(0.0, 0.0))  // Set the position of the marker
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(customMarkerBitmap))  // Use the generated Bitmap as the icon
googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions)  // Add the marker to the GoogleMap instance


How It Works:
Custom Marker Design: The CustomMarkerView composable defines how to draw the marker. In this case, it is a red circle with a black border and centered text.
Composable to Bitmap: The function is createMarkerBitmap. It takes this composable and renders it into a Bitmap. To do this, it uses a Canvas that it draws it onto the Bitmap after first rendering it inside a ComposeView.
Google Maps Marker: Next, this bitmap was converted into a BitmapDescriptor, so that it could be used as the marker icon in Google Maps with the MarkerOptions.
I think this method is more efficient than using the AdvancedMarker and avoids the lag you are experiencing.

Thank you so much for answering, I am using Jetpack Compose, I am not able to get the GoogleMap instance for the last line.

with this solution I've always : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate windowRecomposer; View androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView{76214b5 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} is not attached to a window ; using compose bom : 2024.09.01

You can simply use MarkerComposable instead of Marker as both are available in Marker.kt and moreover, MarkerComposable allows you to use any kind of content as Marker as it internally renders composable as icon using ComposeToBitmapDescriptor!
Sample implementation:
@Composable
fun SimpleMap(
) {
    val latLng = LatLng( -33.8568, 151.2153) // Sydney Opera House lat lng

    val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
        position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(latLng, 14f)
    }
    val mapProperties = remember {
        MapProperties(
            mapType = MapType.HYBRID,
        )
    }
    GoogleMap(
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        properties = mapProperties,
        uiSettings = MapUiSettings(
            myLocationButtonEnabled = false,
            compassEnabled = false,
            mapToolbarEnabled = false
        ),
    ) {
        MarkerComposable(
            state = rememberMarkerState(position = latLng),
            title = "Sydney Opera House"
        ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(100.dp),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Favorite,
                        contentDescription = null,
                        tint = Color.Red,
                        modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
                    )
                    Text("22222", color = Color.White)
                }

        }
    }
}

In above example, i've used Icon, you can keep anything like Image component in place of Icon!


In which version of compose is available? I use compose bom 2024.12.01 and is not present

You need to add maps dependencies:     implementation("com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:4.3.0")     implementation("com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.4")
